# Mysql Match escape email

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I would like to search for an email address in the content field.

```
SELECT *
FROM message m
WHERE MATCH (m.content) AGAINST (
  'robert.oppenheimer@gmail.com' IN BOOLEAN MODE
)
```

Well it finds all the messages where a 'robert' or an 'oppenheimer' is. But i would like it to behave like

```
SELECT *
FROM message m
WHERE m.content LIKE '%robert.oppenheimer@gmail.com%'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you exactly what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM message m
WHERE MATCH (m.content) AGAINST (
  '+"robert.oppenheimer@gmail.com"' IN BOOLEAN MODE
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. But it just finds content like "abc robert.oppenheimer@gmail.com def" but not "abcrobert.oppenheimer@gmail.comdef".

Answer (score 0):

Combine them.

```
SELECT *   
  FROM message m
 WHERE MATCH (m.content) AGAINST ('annie.testman@example.com')
   AND m.content LIKE '%annie.testman@example.com%';
```

Many people realize that `LIKE '%thing%'` is almost always a bad construct, an antipattern even, since every row of the table will be scanned for matches and the query will perform badly (the trailing `%` prevents the use of an index for lookup)... but what many may not realize is that the MySQL optimizer, when faced with multiple `AND` conditions, *all of which must be true*, tries to decide which condition will involve the least amount of work.

Once that's been decided (the "query plan"), the server (ideally, at the storage engine layer) will evaluate that condition first -- no matter which order the conditions appear in the `WHERE` clause -- and will then filter the resulting rows by any remaining criteria.

Fulltext indexes are considered by the optimizer to be one of the best possible choices, so it's going to find the fulltext matches, first, and then remove anything that doesn't also match the `LIKE`, before returning results to you.

The only conditions that immediately come to mind that will typically trump a fulltext search, when it comes to which query plan the optimizer will choose, to process first, would be an indexed column with an equality comparison and no matching value, or an `IMPOSSIBLE WHERE`, such as `WHERE 2 < 1`, both of which of course would always return 0 rows.